# How to generate 3D surface plot of copula in R

Tags: r

I have data and would like to have a surface plot for it. The plot that, I really need to generate, is similar to the one in this site [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_i_interpret_these_Clayton_copula_parameter_0723_graph_in_hydrology#view=5efaf8b6a75d41143e5941d7)

I searched for one week, how to get a similar result but I failed. I tried all the existing method and I also failed.

Could anyone please help me with this problem.

Suppoes my data is as follows:

```
   library(kdecopula)
data(wdbc)  # load data
Mydata <- wdbc[, c(2, 8)]
```

I would like `x=wdbc[, 2]`, `y=wdbc[,  8]` and `z=the density of copula`

Comment: Do you not need 3 fields to get a 3d plot? `Mydata` only has two fields.

Comment: @user2474226 I would like the third filed to be the density of copula

Answer (score 1):

```
library(kdecopula)
data("wdbc")
uv <- apply(wdbc[, c(2, 8)], 2, rank) / (nrow(wdbc) + 1)
fit <- kdecop(uv)
summary(fit)

#> Kernel copula density estimate (tau = 0.47)
#> ------------------------------
#> Variables:    mean radius -- mean concavity 
#> Observations: 569 
#> Method:       Transformation local likelihood, log-quadratic (nearest-neighbor, 'TLL2nn') 
#> Bandwidth:    alpha = 0.3519647
#>               B = matrix(c(0.71, -0.7, 0.7, 0.71), 2, 2)
#> ---
#> logLik: 201.66    AIC: -367.45    cAIC: -366.21    BIC: -289.53 
#> Effective number of parameters: 17.94
```

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = fit$grid, y = fit$grid, z = fit$estimate) %>%
  add_surface()
```

[image]

Sources:

1. [kdecopula: An R Package for the Kernel Estimation of Bivariate Copula Densities](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kdecopula/vignettes/kdecopula.pdf)
2. [3D Surface Plots in R with plotly](https://plotly.com/r/3d-surface-plots/?utm_source=mailchimp-jan-2015&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=generalemail-jan2015&utm_term=surface-chart)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. The density and the surface should follow the expected copula.

Comment: @Maryam updated. I believe it now plots what you need.

Comment: Thanks so much. I want the values of x and y to be the original values, not the copula values.

Comment: I think what  I really need is here, https://r4hydrology.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/bivariate-flood-frequency-analysis-by-r-copula-function/.